# C++ function to find max & minimum values

Tags: c++, arrays, function, max

I am trying to make a function that will, once called upon, read values from a data file and give four outputs: Maximum Positive value, minimum positive value, maximum negative value, and minimum negative value. If there are no positive values it should output "No positive values," and the same for negative. **The major problem I am running into is getting it to return the correct minimum negative value.**

Here is what I have so far.

```
void maxMinimum (double x[], int n)
{
   int i;
   double posMaximum;
   double posMinimum;
   double negMaximum;
   double negMinimum;
   double max;
   double min;

   posMaximum = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] > posMaximum)
         posMaximum = x[i];
   }  
   cout << "       Maximum positive value       = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << right << posMaximum << endl;

   posMinimum = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] < posMinimum)   if(x[i] > 0.0)
         posMinimum = x[i];
   }
   cout << "       Minimum positive value       = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << right << posMinimum << endl;

   negMaximum = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] < negMaximum)   if(x[i] < 0.0)
         negMaximum = x[i];
   }
   cout << "       Maximum negative value       = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << right << negMaximum << endl;

   negMinimum = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if (x[i] < 0.0 && x[i] < negMaximum)
      negMinimum = x[i];
   }

   cout << "       Minimum negative value = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(8) << right << negMinimum << endl << endl;

   max = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] > max)
         max = x[i];
   }

   min = x[0];
   for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
   {
      if(x[i] < min)
         min = x[i];
   }

   if(max < 0.0)
       cout << "       No positive values" << endl;
   if(min >= 0.0)
       cout << "       No negative values" << endl << endl;  

}
```

When executed the function will return positive values for the minimum negative value. Which to me makes no sense due to `if (x[i] < 0.0 && x[i] < negMaximum)`. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Note: Minimum negative value refers to the value closest to zero. Maximum negative value is farthest from zero.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: min and max negative appear to be doing the same thing (finding the most negative value).  Also add some more parens: ((x[i] < 0.0) && (x[i] < negMaximum)).   For min you need to find the least negative number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

negMinimum will be greater than negMaximum, as in -5 > -30. You will also have to create a temporary variable otherwise negMinimum will only equal the last negative value checked that is greater than negMaximum.
Eg your data is {0,-80,5,-2,6,-8} negMinimum will equal -8 since -8 < 0 and -8 > -80.
So you need to change x[i] < negMaximum to x[i] > negMaximum and introduce a variable to act as a new check condition each loop.

```
negMinimum = x[0];
double temp = negMaximum
  for (i=0; i <= n-1; i++)
 {
   if ((x[i] < 0.0) && (x[i] > temp))
   {
   negMinimum = x[i];
   temp = negMinimum;
   }
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Quick, easy fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your design. Namely try to write four methods like this

```
double minPositive;
void nextValueForMinPositive(double next);

void maxMinimum(double x[], int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;

    minPositive = x[0]; //std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    std::for_each(x, x + n, nextValueForMinPositive);
}

void nextValueForMinPositive(double next) {
     if (next > 0.0 && next < minPositive)
         minPositive = next;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. What would be the advantages of writing it this way opposed to the other? Geniunely wondering.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Simplify your problem as much as possible. Do not fight with it at once. First solve one problem and pass to the next (find min positive, if it works pass to implementing max positive) and try to distribute responsibility between functions, classes.. Your function tries to find four values in one function. Last: upvote if you like.